# Find and replace with two (somewhat) uncorrelated random variables

Tags: notepad++, notepad

EDIT : 
I have changed my topic name to (hopefully) more accurately reflect my request. I am looking to include the two variables circled in the photo below, so as not to alter anything outside of said range. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXCtY.png

Thank you

```
   Num {
   Desc("AddlPointRadius (Enter 1 in NOTES To Unhide \"MixPointMod\")")
   Name("AddlPointRadius")
   Hide(0)
   HideVar("ToggleTpRvsTpSqEval")
   HideUnused(0)
   ClrHide(1)
   Req(0)
   Uom("")
   MPTko("Pg")
   QtyTxt(0)
   Notes("")
   ProjDflt(0)
   LCol(0)
   LColTot(0)
   Dec(3)
   Dflt(".3")
   Max("5.000")
   Min("0.000")
  }
```

(original)
I have a very large text file that I am trying to do a massive find and replace. My problem is that the values that I am trying to replace are all random. Is there any way that I can find and replace all of the random values with a single value? I have uploaded a picture of the value I am trying to replace. I would like to take all of the random values and replace them with .13

Here is a picture with an example of the value

https://i.stack.imgur.com/flS18.png

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You should be able to find a Regular Expression that will catch all of the random numbers you want.  Notepad++ allows you to find and replace with regular expressions. What are the numbers you are replacing? Are you replacing any and all numbers?

Comment: Please, don't post text as images. It's impossible to copy in editor for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `Num\s*\{[^}]+Name\("AddlPointRadius"\)[^}]+Dflt\("\K[^"]+`
- Replace with: `.13`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
Num\s*\{                    # literally
[^}]+                       # 1 or more non closing curly brace
Name\("AddlPointRadius"\)   # literally
[^}]+                       # 1 or more non closing curly brace
Dflt\("                     # literally
\K                          # forget all we have seen until this position
[^"]+                       # 1 or more non quote (i.e. the value to be changed)
```

**Replacement:**

```
.13         # the new value
```

**Given:** (I've shortened your example)

```
Num {
   Desc("AddlPointRadius (Enter 1 in NOTES To Unhide \"MixPointMod\")")
   Name("AddlPointRadius")
   LColTot(0)
   Dec(3)
   Dflt(".3")
   Max("5.000")
   Min("0.000")
}
Num {
   Desc("AddlPointRadius (Enter 1 in NOTES To Unhide \"MixPointMod\")")
   Name("SomethingElse")
   LColTot(0)
   Dec(3)
   Dflt(".3")
   Max("5.000")
   Min("0.000")
}
Num {
   Desc("AddlPointRadius (Enter 1 in NOTES To Unhide \"MixPointMod\")")
   Name("AddlPointRadius")
   LColTot(0)
   Dec(3)
   Dflt(".3")
   Max("5.000")
   Min("0.000")
}
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Num {
   Desc("AddlPointRadius (Enter 1 in NOTES To Unhide \"MixPointMod\")")
   Name("AddlPointRadius")
   LColTot(0)
   Dec(3)
   Dflt(".13")
   Max("5.000")
   Min("0.000")
}
Num {
   Desc("AddlPointRadius (Enter 1 in NOTES To Unhide \"MixPointMod\")")
   Name("SomethingElse")
   LColTot(0)
   Dec(3)
   Dflt(".3")
   Max("5.000")
   Min("0.000")
}
Num {
   Desc("AddlPointRadius (Enter 1 in NOTES To Unhide \"MixPointMod\")")
   Name("AddlPointRadius")
   LColTot(0)
   Dec(3)
   Dflt(".13")
   Max("5.000")
   Min("0.000")
}
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: @Charango12: May I know why you have unaccepted my answer? Doesn't it work?

Comment: My apologies. I'm still new to the interface. I clicked the check next to your answer. This is what you're referring to right?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

One way to do it is to use the find and replace feature activating regular expressions.

1. Open find and replace dialog
2. Check "Regular expression" box in the bottom left corner
3. Fill **Find what:** with `Dflt\("[.,0-9]*"\)`
4. Fill **Replace with:** with `Dflt(".13")`

Run it.

#### Explanation:

This regular expression represents any string that starts with `Dflt("`, followed by any amount of `.`s, `,` or numeric digits in any order and then followed by `")`

The `\`s in the **Find what** field are used to escape the parentheses and allow them to be matched exactly, since `(` and `)` have a specific function in regular expressions.

The search will match any piece of the file that matches this pattern and then replace with the contents you specified.

Comment: This works, but i am now running into a different problem. There are other places in my work that contain Dflt\("[.,0-9]*"\) that i do not want changed. Is there any way that I can perform a larger find/replace that includes the entire string of characters that i posted above? Thank you for your reply and help.

Comment: I have included another picture in the original post showing the other variable that I wish to capture.

Comment: @Charango12 I am sorry that I did not manage to serve your needs to its completion! I am happy that this answer actually helped you in some way, at least so that you would find your real problem. If you think I deserve it, give my answer a +1 

Comment: I need 15 reputation before it will record my +1. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with a regular expression.

Here is an example. To replace all occurences of **Dflt(".#")**
 with  **Dflt(".13")**

1. Open up Search and replace (Ctrl + H)
2. Change the search mode from normal to Regular expression
3. Use this regular expression: `(Dflt\(".[0-9]*"\))` in the 'Find what' box
4. Put `Dflt\(".13"\)` in the 'Replace with' text box (Replace ".13" with whatever value you need)
5. Replace All

[image]

Comment: You just switched the Option name from `Dflt` to `Dftl`